# Why exactly was my youtube question closed again?

Tags: discussion, moderation, close-reasons, closed-questions

I noticed with amusement that my [youtube question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52725/why-do-my-youtube-videos-play-for-two-seconds-then-stop) from almost a year ago (!!!) was closed today. Our esteemed [Mr. Edwards](https://askubuntu.com/users/24694/jacob-johan-edwards) deemed it offtopic. According to him this should rather be a bug report.

I politely disagree. As he himself stated:

> it's a closed source flash issue, so that [meaning a bug report] might not help much.

So I think it's a valid question since I was looking for a work around. The bug has already been reported without any effect and there will most certainly be no bugfix from Adobe in the future (considering Adobe announced the current version would be the last flash released for linux).

No hard feelings, I don't know you, Mr. Edwards, but my humble opinion is, that you have been a bit too eager here. Not that I'd expect an answer to my question or that it was particularly precious to me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Probably closed precisely (no pun intended) because it was so old and unresolved....

Answer (score 5):

All questions can be reopened.

I note that the last edit on your question was 13 July 2011.  We do need OP's to maintain their questions, providing updates (lets say weekly, fortnightly etc) as to what they have tried.  It could also have been construed as too-localised since no updates have been made since then.

There also some information that would be helpful that is currently lacking - ubuntu version, desktop-environment, flash version, graphics card, graphics driver.  Any particular videos, links (if not unappropriate) - have you got multiple versions of flash, gnash installed.  Have you tried the latest version of lightspark? Does this happen with HTML5 videos.

You've also tagged the Q as a "bug" and "I'm thinking of reporting a bug".  As I'm sure you are fully aware, bug-reports are off-topic for this site and should be reported to launchpad.

As I said at the outset - happy to reopen your question - but first, have a think about the above.

Comment: I abandoned the question as the problem occurs much more rarely now and honestly don't care anymore. Thus I also don't care if it's re-opened or not. The last edit being in last July was precisely the point that made me wonder: It seems like an unnecessary hassle to close all abandoned questions. Also there is always the off-chance someone answers it later. So why close it? ... As to the bug report - back than I wasn't aware. Now it doesn't qualify as a bug anymore as there will be no fix. I was simply curious... Thanks for the insight.